# best_in_place :collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, best-in-place

I'm using the following view code in my Ruby (1.9.3) on Rails (3.1) application to edit who a task is owned by.

```
=simple_form_for task do |f|
  =f.input :owner, collection: task.list.collaborators
```

Which produces the following selection dropdown.

[image]

How do I tell it to display the `first_name` and `last_name` of the user?

Note:

Tasks belong to lists which belong to collaborations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, `task.list.collaborators` needs to be in nested array form as [[key, value], [key, value]].  A simple way to do that:

```
task.list.collaborators.map{|user| [user.id, "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"]}
```

Alternatively, you can do the following.  Add a method to User as you would want it displayed:

```
class User
  def select_label
    "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
  end
end
```

Then use the :label_method and :value_method parameters:

```
f.input :owner, 
  collection: task.list.collaborators, 
  label_method: :select_label, 
  value_method: :id
```

Comment: I added another option, which may be cleaner and more reusable for you

Answer (score 0):

You could also also define a `#to_s` method on `User`

```
class User
  def to_s
    "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
  end
end
```

That way your collection can be:

```
task.list.collaborators.map { |user| [user.id, user] }
```